# Change errorbar thickness in Altair

Tags: python, altair

How can I change the thickness of my errorbars in Altair?
When I tried to change the color to black, it turns out than it should be.
Why is that?

My expected output is

[image: expected output]

But the actual output is

[image: my output]

Here is my code

```py
import altair as alt
alt.Chart(df2).mark_errorbar(color='black').encode(
    alt.X(
        "quantile95",
        axis=alt.Axis(title="lower",tickMinStep=5),
        scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 55])
    )
).properties(width=450, height=20)
```

Comment: `df2` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Since no data was provided, I used the data from the official reference to create the expected output.
One is a box plot and the other is an overlaid strip plot.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()
error_bar_s = alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot(color='black').encode(
    x=alt.X("yield:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title="lower", tickMinStep=5), scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, source['yield'].max()+10])),
    y=alt.Y('variety:N')
).properties(width=450, height=450)

strip = alt.Chart(source).mark_tick(color='red').encode(
    x='yield:Q',
    y='variety:N'
)
error_bar_s + strip
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Iris dataset as example this will be the necessary code

```py
from vega_datasets import data  # pip install vega_datasets
import altair as alt

dataset = data.iris()

ticks = alt.Chart(dataset).mark_tick().encode(
    alt.X('sepalWidth', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
)

mean_point = alt.Chart(dataset).mark_circle().encode(
    x=alt.X('mean(sepalWidth)'),
    color=alt.value("black"),
    size=alt.value(50)
)

errorbar = alt.Chart(dataset).mark_errorbar(extent='stdev', ticks=True).encode(
    x=alt.X('sepalWidth'),
    color=alt.value("black"),
    strokeWidth=alt.value(5)
)

errorbar + mean_point + ticks
```

Output:

[image]

Some key remarks:

- If ticks are not needed, remove the `ticks` parameter in the mark_errobar
- The "thickness" of the CI is the `strokeWidth` parameter in the encode of the mark_errorbar
- The extend parameter could be `"ci"`, `"stdev"`, `"stderr"`, `"iqr"`. See [docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.ErrorBarDef.html)